# Detect images in landscape format and cut them into two portraits

Tags: bash, pdf, imagemagick, crop, imagemagick-convert

I have scanned documents in PDF format. These documents contain pages in portrait format of one page and in landscape format of two pages.

I will need to perform OCR processing on them, but I will need to re-format them using a bash script.

I can extract the images from the PDF with `pdfimages`, put them together with `img2pdf` and perform OCR processing with `ocrmypdf`.

But I struggle with the utilities of **[ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php)** to detect their orientation and if necessary cut them into two images in portrait mode. You should know that not all scans are the same size and that portrait and landscape images are mixed within the same PDF.

From now I only have the begin of a script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.pdf;
do
  # Créer le fichier PDF avec OCR
  ocrmypdf --language fra --deskew --remove-background --clean-final --optimize 3 "$i" OCR/"$i"
done
```

And some tests like:
`pdfimages "MyFile.pdf" tmp/"MyFile"`
and `img2pdf tmp/*.ppm | ocrmypdf --language fra --deskew --remove-background --clean-final --optimize 3 - OCR/"MyFile.pdf"`

Anyone have an idea how to perform these tests and have a document with only portrait pages in it?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: please post code and describe what you tried and how you failed.

Comment: don't put this it in a comment, edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's okay, I finally managed to write my script. I'll share it here in case anyone needs it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for pdf in *.pdf;
do
  # Displays the PDF file to be processed
  echo "Processing of file \"$pdf\"…"

  # Temporary folder
  TmpRep="/tmp/conversion$(date +%Y%m%d)$(date +%H%M%S)"
  mkdir --parents "$TmpRep"

  # Extract the PDF to the temporary directory
  pdfimages "$pdf" "$TmpRep/${pdf%.pdf}"

  for img in "$TmpRep"/*.ppm;
  do
    # Retrieves the image sizes
    Width=$(identify -format "%w" "$img")
    Height=$(identify -format "%h" "$img")

    # Checks if the image is landscape
    if [ $Width -gt $Height ]
    then
      # Cutting into two portraits
      convert "$img" -crop 2x1@ "${img%.*}_%d.ppm"

      # Deletes the original
      rm "$img"
    fi
  done

  # Create the PDF file with OCR from the images
  img2pdf "$TmpRep"/*.ppm | ocrmypdf --language eng --deskew --remove-background --clean-final --tesseract-timeout 240 --optimize 3 - "${pdf%.pdf} - OCR.pdf"

  # Deletes the temporary folder
  rm -rf "$TmpRep"/
  echo "Processing of file \"$pdf\" done."
done
```

This script processes all the PDF files in the current directory. It extracts the images into a temporary directory. Cuts the landscape images in half. Recreates a PDF file on which it performs OCR processing. And some cleanup.
The new PDF end with *OldName - OCR.pdf*.

Comment: That's pretty tidy! You could consider setting `nullglob` at the top in case there are no files, or images. You could merge the two `date` commands into one by just joining up the parameters from both calls. You could get the height and width of an image in one go with `read Width Height < <(identify -format "%w %h" "$img" )` Have my vote:-)

Comment: I didn't know this tips. Thank :-)